# VHDL : Assign specific wires from a bus?

Tags: vhdl

I'm fairly new to VHDL: is there a way to select specific elements from a larger sized vector to pass as a smaller vector to a port? I have the following example to demonstrate my problem:

```
-- tst.vhd: a 4 input AND gate
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity tst is
    port(x : in  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
         y : out std_logic);
end tst;

architecture dataflow of tst is
begin
    y <= x(0) and x(1) and x(2) and x(3);
end dataflow;

-- foo.vhd: demonstrate the issue
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity foo is
end foo;

architecture sim of foo is
    signal data : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0) := x"FA01";
    signal y : std_logic;
begin
    uut : entity work.foo(sim)
          port map(input => data(3, 5, 9, 11), y => y); -- problematic line
    process begin
        wait for 10 ns;
        report "data: " & to_string(data(3, 5, 9, 11)); -- problematic line
        report "y: "    & to_string(y);
        wait;
    end process;
end sim;
```

As you can see I only want lines numbered 3, 5, 9, 11 from the 16-bit bus name "data" to be converted into another 4-bit vector. However I get the following compilation error:

```
ghdl -a --std=08 tst.vhd
ghdl -a --std=08 foo.vhd
foo.vhd:12:41: number of indexes mismatches array dimension
                  port map(input => data(3, 5, 9, 11), y => y);
                                        ^
foo.vhd:15:49: number of indexes mismatches array dimension
                report "data: " & to_string(data(3, 5, 9, 11));
                                                ^
make: *** [Makefile:3: all] Error 1
```

Is there a proper way to do this?

Comment: you might find the concatenation operator useful

Comment: Selected subset of elements of a named value(data) can be associated with a formal of a port map (x not input) of mode in as an expression in -2008 of the form of an aggregate. Elements of formal x can also be associated individually with elements of actual data in -1993 and later. The to_string parameter can be an aggregate in a qualified expression. You could simply use an intermediary signal assigned an aggregate as an expression. The formal parameter to to_string is anonymous and [can be positional associated as an aggregate in a qualified expression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYr4u.jpg).

Comment: Note the changes to the uut instantiation, the entity and architecture name and the first formal port name switched from input to x.

Comment: Proper has a specific dictionary meaning in *Is there a proper way to do this?*. There appear to be either four or five proper ways to provide a solution. The answer to your yes/no questions (*... is there a way to select specific elements from a larger sized vector to pass as a smaller vector to a port?*) would be yes in both cases. A -2008 LRM would be a helpful resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate all "snippets" as you like to an intermediate signal.

```vhdl
architecture sim of foo is
    signal data : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0) := x"FA01";
    signal x : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    signal y : std_logic;
begin
    x <= data(3) & data(5) & data(9) & data(11);
    uut : entity work.tst(dataflow)
          port map(x => x, y => y);
    process begin
        wait for 10 ns;
        report "data: " & to_string(x);
        report "y: "    & to_string(y);
        wait;
    end process;
end sim;
```

More issues of your source, already correct above:

- Architecture and entity of your unit under test were the ones of the test bench, not the entity you want to test.
- The input signal had changed names.